# How to get Spring/Gradle to recognize JdbcTemplate initialization

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, spring-jdbc

I have created a small SpringBoot/Gradle REST controller application, but I am
having problems initializing a connection to a Postgresql database.  My application
includes the following class that's used to access the database:

```
@Component
public class UserSettingDAO {
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    ...
}
```

In the first version of the program, I included the following in `/src/main/resources/application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://...
spring.datasource.username=...
spring.datasource.password=...
```

In this version, my REST service *successfully* connected with the database.  However,
for consistency with other projects in my group, I changed the initialization of 
`dataSource` and `jdbcTemplate` as follows:

First, I removed those property 
definitions above from `application.properties`.  Next, I created  an XML initialization file `resources/resources_deployment1/spring-resource1.xml` that included the
following:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations" value="classpath:pdao_connection.properties"/>
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"> 
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
</bean>
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

where the referenced file `resources/resources_deployment1/pdao_connection.properties`
contains the following:

```
driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
db.username=...
db.password=...
url=jdbc:postgresql://...
```

After this, when I then deployed my application (to Websphere Liberty) and hit my REST
service from Chrome, it *failed* with the following message:

```
Failed to auto-configure a DataSource: 'spring.datasource.url' is not specified and no embedded datasource could be auto-configured.
```

It seems like there is a break in the long chain of references so that Spring does
not have access to the required connection parameters.   How can I fix this, while
keeping the deployment-specific parameters in a subfolder of `resources`?  In
particular, how do I convince the build and runtime operations to look in the
`resources/resources_deployment1` folder?

Answer (score 0):

it required artifacts spring-jdbc and postgresql java connector inside your web.xml or pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon an answer:   Adding the following piece of code in the same package where I'm using `jdbcTemplate`

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:spring-resource1.xml")
public class DAOConfiguration {
}
```

appears to let Spring know that it should look in the referenced XML file that is, in fact, under the project's `resources/` directory.